# Batch Job to delete specific live agent's chat transcript after 100 days

Tags: apex, batch, liveagent, scheduled-job, livechattranscript

There are 4 live agent chats enabled in our org. I have to create batch job, that deletes only our division's live chat transcript once it pasts 100 days. what would be the condition or criteria I can use on LiveChatTranscript standard object. I didn't find anything similar to recordtype that indicates our live agent. How can this be implemented.

Comment: what does "4 live agent chats" mean? Do you have 4 different agent configurations (`LiveChatUserConfigSettings`), chat buttons (`LiveChatButtonSettings`), or chat deployments (`LiveChatDeploymentSettings`), or something else?

Comment: Meaning there are 4 business divisions which has their own live agent settings. Button settings are different, agent configs are different, every setup got their own requirements. I had to setup a live agent chat from step 1 , for us it lead and for other divisions it is either contact/case object.

Comment: There's `LiveChatButtonId` and `LiveChatDeploymentId` on [LiveChatTranscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_livechattranscript.htm). And if it's only Lead, there's `LeadId`